# Generating automatic ID

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to generate automatic id of type `ame100`, `ame101` and so on, so that as soon as I start my Android application, the next value of the series `ame***` which is currently not in the database, should come automatically in edittext. So that on submitting the form I should have that value in database.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your primary key autoincrement, so that db will generate the next value.
2. Each time you need new id, just ask your databse for MAX(ID) from your table.
3. Increment it and set to edittext!

Note: this solution works only if you have one place of inserting the values.

I would suggest not showing the number before inserting, but create it after, when you already have generated id of the object.

Comment: sir, i am getting problem in third part of the step..Which listener should i set so that it can automatically enter the generated value in orderid edittext..i have tried with onClicListener but it's not working..plz help me!